# Device Disconnection during Android Accessory Mode

Tags: android, usb, accessory

Is it possible to programatically detect if my device got disconnected (USB)?

I'm trying to flag a disconnection event in my accessory mode application.
So is it possible? if Yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a BroadcastReceiver to listen for UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED and UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED events.

```
<receiver android:name="UsbConnectionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED">
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Or you could periodically cycle through the connected devices (using a timer or the ScheduledExecutorService) checking if your device is in the list.

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
UsbDevice device = deviceList.get("deviceName");

UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
if (usbDeviceIsMyDevice(device)){
    // your code
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will likely not be able to use `UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACH` or `UsbManagerACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACH` since `UsbManager` only supports the Android hosting the usb connection. From Android Developer docs for `UsbManager`:

> This class allows you to access the state of USB and communicate with USB devices. Currently only host mode is supported in the public API.

Android Accessory does not allow the Android to host the usb connection, but rather requires the attached device to do so. I was able to detect and accessory disconnect in my application by having a background service regularly run the following custom method.

```
void checkForAccessory(){
        UsbAccessory[] deviceList = mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();
        if (deviceList != null){
            // My app checks if the device has already been initialized or if it needs to be initialized.
        } else {
            // Perform actions associated with a disconnect
        }
    }
```

As long as `checkForAccessory()` is run frequently, you will get a fairly up-to-date detection of an accessory disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager#ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED), which was there since API level 12.

Simply register a `BroadcastReceiver` for it, like so:

```kotlin
val detachedFilter = IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED)
context.registerReceiver(usbReceiver, detachedFilter)
```

Where the `usbReceiver` would look similar to this:

```kotlin
object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val action = intent.action
        if (action == UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED) {
            // Do something about it
        }
    }
}
```